# How to use linear interpolation inside GODOT

Tags: input, timedelta, godot, linear-interpolation

I'm trying to make a smooth camera movement using linear interpolation, but looks like I cannot pass Delta with it.. not sure if that is the problem. Instead it just snaps its position

CameraBase is only a spatial 3D, and the actual camera Node is his child node

```
func _unhandled_input(event):
    if event.is_action_released("ui_focus_next"):
        i += 1
        if i >= allies.size():
            i = 0
        pointer.translation = allies[i].translation + Vector3(0,5,0)
        focus_camera(allies[i])


func focus_camera(target):
    var move = $CameraBase.translation.linear_interpolate(target.translation, CAMERA_SPEED)
    $CameraBase.set_translation(move)
```

It would work fine if was using Input instead of unhandle, but I read that is not the proper way to do it

Comment: Maybe the camera speed is too extreme, have you tried different numbers and also unhandled input is a bit weird try using a normal physics process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us have a look at the documentation for [`linear_interpolate`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector3.html#class-vector3-method-linear-interpolate):

> `Vector3 linear_interpolate ( Vector3 to, float weight )`
>
> Returns the result of the linear interpolation between this vector and to by amount t. weight is on the range of 0.0 to 1.0, representing the amount of interpolation.

As you can see the second parameter is a weight. If it is 0.0, you get a vector without modification. If it is 1.0, you get the vector you pass as first parameter. Any value between 0.0 and 1.0 will give a point in between.

We can confirm this in in ["Vector Interpolation"](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/math/interpolation.html#vector-interpolation):

> Here is simple pseudo-code for going from point A to B using interpolation:
>
> ```
> func _physics_process(delta):
>    t += delta * 0.4
>
>    $Sprite.position = $A.position.linear_interpolate($B.position, t)
> ```
>
> It will produce the following motion:
>
> [image: Circle moving from pint A to point B, as t goes from 0 to 1]

To reiterate, a `weight` of 0.0 give you the first position and a `weight` 1.0 gives you the second position. For the motion you are meant to pass a value that varies from 0.0 to 1.0 over time.

Which is why the example uses `_physics_process` and `delta` (which is in in seconds, by the way). Every physics frame, Godot calls `_physics_process`, where the code computes the new value for the `weight` (the `t` variable in this case) using the elapsed time since the last time Godot called `_physics_process` (that is `delta`).

If you want to use `linear_interpolate` to create motion, you must use it similar fashion. Calling it from `_process`, `_physics_process`, or from the handler the `timeout` signal of a `Timer` or similar solution.

---

However, I'm going to suggest an entirely different approach: use a [`Tween`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tween.html) node.

You can add a `Tween` node and use it for your interpolation. You can add the node in the editor, and take a reference like this:

```
onready var tween:Tween = $Tween
```

Or you can create it from code like this:

```
var tween:Tween

func _ready():
    tween = Tween.new()
    add_child(tween)
```

Either way, once you have a variable with the Tween, we can use it like this:

```
    tween.interpolate_property($CameraBase, "translation",
        $CameraBase.translation, target.translation, duration)
```

That can be in `_input` or `_unhandled_input` or anywhere, it does not matter. Nor does it need `delta`. And you don't need to call it multiple times (which is what you have to do to get motion with `linear_interpolate`, in case that wasn't clear).

The code is telling the `Tween` node to interpolate the `translation` property of `$CameraBase`. The values will go from the current value of `$CameraBase.translation` to `target.translation`. And the motion will take `duration` seconds.

We can tweak this to use speed:

```
    var distance = $CameraBase.translation.distance_to(target.translation)
    var duration = distance / CAMERA_SPEED
    tween.interpolate_property($CameraBase, "translation",
        $CameraBase.translation, target.translation, duration)
```

*This assumes `CAMERA_SPEED` is units per second.*

Also let us not forget to call `start`:

```
    tween.start()
```

And, as as bonus, [`interpolate_property`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tween.html#class-tween-method-interpolate-property) and the other interpolation `Tween` methods allow you to specify the kind of interpolation (it is linear by default), by passing a [`TransitionType`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tween.html#enum-tween-transitiontype) and a [`EaseType`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tween.html#enum-tween-easetype).

By the way, you can check [`is_active`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tween.html#class-tween-method-is-active) to find out if the `Tween` is running, and there are also [`stop`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tween.html#class-tween-method-stop) and [`stop_all`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tween.html#class-tween-method-stop-all) methods.

Comment: That was really handy, tween is working perfeclty fine, the only thing that was missing on the answer is to put ``` tween.start() ```` at the end of the tween code