# How do I add the sliding transitions in games such as Mega Man,The Legend of Zelda, and Metroid in my Godot game?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Sorry for the long question title. I'm pretty new here.

So my question is just as it the title above. I've tried mostly everything and have searched everywhere on the internet. Some pseudo leads I've tried were `.linear_interpolate("my screen width" , "my screen height)` or even examining other people's code studying it and maybe looking for a way to use it.

What I'm trying to accomplish is at least allowing the player to move around part of a larger level scroll the camera up to that bound of the level then scroll the camera using tween to another bound of the same scene and so on and so forth.

I don't really even need the whole thing with tweens all I need is a way to implement Camera2D bounds that allow me to implement a tween node to complete it.

Please help!

Comment: See also [How to use linear interpolation inside GODOT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67864095/402022).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't really even need the whole thing with tweens all I need is a way to implement Camera2D bounds that allow me to implement a tween node to complete it.

Limiting the `Camera2D` is the easy part. Either the camera does not follow the player at all (e.g. Zelda for NES), in which case you only need the tweens.

Or…

> What I'm trying to accomplish is at least allowing the player to move around part of a larger level scroll the camera up to that bound of the level then scroll the camera using tween to another bound of the same scene and so on and so forth.

The camera follows the player, until it reaches some limits… Which you can define with the properties `limit_left`, `limit_top`, `limit_right` and `limit_bottom` of the `Camera2D`. Set them to the bounds of the rectangle you want to limit the `Camera2D` to.

---

I remind you that the `Camera2D` hitting the limit is not what should trigger the transition. What should trigger the transition is the player character hitting the limit… And you can handle that with `Area2D` since the player character - usually - is a physics object.

So you would handle the signals of the `Area2D` and form there you update the camera limits, do any tweens you need, or whatever the case might be.

Comment: What do you recommend for the way to limit it while still being able to scroll through the screen. I now know what type of Tween interpolate to use but for some reason I'm stuck on only being able to limit the camera up to a point

Comment: @Rusty_Pipes I tried to set up a general solution. Tween: easy. Limit: easy. Both… No so much. Using `Area2D` and handling body entered and body exited seems to be a good approach. You limit the `Camera2D` according to the `Area2D`, and you know when to tween. One issue is where to tween to. I suppose you could add some `Position2D`. But remember you need to change limits to allow the tween, and the moment you change the limits the camera will move. So, I'm making the the target something other than the character. It feels hacky. If I come up with a better solution I'll update the answer.

Comment: Ok so I have some good news. I found this tutorial on github called [RoomBasedCamera](https://github.com/Harrison-Miller/RoomBasedCamera/blob/master/Player.gd). However while it can scroll up to a point which I wanted. I can't implement my custom transition. Which uses [this](https://github.com/nezvers/Godot_Public_Examples/blob/master/Zelda_camera_transition/src/Objects/Camera.gd)